# xPath query doesn't work on this website

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

Here is my code to grab title of website:

```
$finder = new DomXPath($doc);
$title = $finder->query('/html/head/title')->item(0)->textContent;
die($title);
```

It work correctly in some websites:
http://www.beytoote.com/news/politics-social/jnews151207.html

But not work in this particular web page:
http://www.jamnews.ir/detail/News/742550

Where is the problem?

Comment: How exactly is it supposed to work?

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov It just return the a text (page title tag's text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use php cURL or file_get_contents this particular website seems to block it giving an error message. If you set the user agent it seems OK. Also I would run it through php-tidy in case of errors in the HTML.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.jamnews.ir/detail/News/742550');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
$source = curl_exec($ch);
$config = array(
           'indent'         => true,
           'output-xhtml'   => true,
           'force-output'   => true,
           'wrap'           => 200);

$tidy = new tidy;
$tidy->parseString($source, $config, 'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($tidy);
$finder = new DomXPath($doc);
$title = $finder->query('/html/head/title')->item(0)->textContent;
die($title);
```

gives:

```
جام نیوز :: JamNews - اجازه عربستان به اسرائیل برای حمله به ایران
```

Comment: This is not quite what I want, but it helped very much, Tnx.

Comment: Have you got it working now or do you need any further help?

Comment: I didn't use php-tidy, It's not necessary, I just use curl with setting CURLOPT_USERAGENT and it worked well.